# none return value function in Golang

Tags: function, go

While I was reading "the little go" book, I found that it suggests to write a function without any return value. So I proceed to test that function but the program won't compile and give me this "... used as value"error. Anyone knows what is going on here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func log(message string) {
    fmt.Println(message)
}

func main() {
    msg := log("just a message")
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

I know that this function is trivial (maybe the question is stupid also). But I am just curious to know if this type of function legal in Go?

Comment: Of corse this is legal. What is illegal is `msg := log()` because log doesn't return anything which could be assigned to msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function here you have used

```
func log(message string){
    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

Actually returns nothing.

But you are assigning it to a variable is incorrect. Since function returns nothing.

```
msg := log("just a message")
```

and that's why the error

> .. used as value

You can call it directly.

```
func main() {
    log("just a message")
}
```

Check out on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4yZJAfDl6mn)

Comment: your answer solved my question. So just a follow-up: if a function returns nothing then it means we can call it directly?

Comment: yes ofcourse we can call it directly. Since your function already contains a code `fmt.Println(message)` to prints a message on screen.

Comment: aha, thanks! Now I see it. For some reason, when I see function like this `func log(message string)` (with arguments in it), I automatically thought I should assign something to the method so it can be used. But it is already usable. Thanks.

Comment: No when a function returns nothing you need not to assign it to a variable

Comment: yeah, I think this is a basic rule in programming or sth like that? But I am not quite familiar with it I think

Comment: Invite to chat to discuss things This is not a place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165781/discussion-between-himanshu-and-maoyi).

Answer (score 2):

A function that returns nothing is perfectly valid:

```
func log(message string) {
    // .. do stuff
}
```

But treating it as though it returns something is invalid:

```
msg := log("foo") // what do you expect to be assigned to msg? log() returns nothing!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log() function does not return anything so you can’t assign it result to a variable (msg := ...)

```
import(
  "fmt"
   )

func log(message string){
  fmt.Println(message)
}

func main(){
  log("just a message")
}
```